# How to set value from database in dropdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I managed to add a data from dropdown going to database. My problem is when I want to edit, I cant see the value from database that I add going to dropdown. I know that my problem lies in the edit_class_view.php file.

Here is my edit_class_view.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> School Year-Semester:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php
                echo form_open('main/editClass');
                $options = array(
                    '' => 'Select School Year and Semester',
                    'SY 2016-2017 2nd Sem' => 'SY 2016-2017 2nd Sem',
                    'SY 2017 Summer' => 'SY 2017 Summer',
                    'SY 2017-2018 1st Sem' => 'SY 2017-2018 1st Sem',
                );
                echo "<div class='drop_pos'>";
                echo form_dropdown('sys', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'required="required"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"', '<?php echo $row->$School_Year_Semester;?>');
                ?>
                <br>
                <div class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('sys');
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using Codeigniter 3. Please refer correct syntax of form_dropdown https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

You need to do changes like. You have typo error in `<?php echo $row->$School_Year_Semester;?>`

**$row->$School_Year_Semester** it should be **$row->School_Year_Semester**

```
$selected = 'CSE';  // default value
// check if row is set while editing; get its value
if (isset($row->School_Year_Semester)) {
  $selected = $row->School_Year_Semester;
}

// Set all other attributes for dropdown
$attribures = array("class" => "btn dropdown-toggle",
  "required" => "required" , "data-toggle" => "dropdown-menu");

echo form_dropdown('sys', $options, $selected, $attributes);
```

Comment: CSE is not included in my codes. It is only
    'echo form_dropdown('sys', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'required="required"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"', '<?php echo $row->$School_Year_Semester;?>');'

Comment: Can you show what is print_r($row) also i have taken from your code only 'CSE' if its not there you can make other value as default selection